# c# object to string to display it in text format

Tags: c#, object, render

I have the next object/list "ListaDatos" and I like to get it as clear string (to visualize/send this via mail, etc)

```
public List<Datos> ListaDatos = new List<Datos>();

public class Datos
{
    public string Numero;
    public string Alias;
    public string URLConsumo;

    //-- Consumos ----------------------------- 
    public List<Consumo> Consumos = new List<Consumo>();
    public string ConsumoTotal;
}

public class Consumo 
{
    public string Tipo;
    public string Subtipo;
    public string Concepto;
    public string Cantidad;
    public string Importe;
    public string Total;
}
```

What is the easiest way to "render" this object into text to obtain a string variable with something like this:

```
DATOS
 Numero     : 10
 Alias      : "aaaaa"
 urlConsumo : "www.aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
 Consumos
  Tipo      : "abc"
  SubTtipo  : "aaa"
  ...
DATOS
 Numero     : 10
 Alias      : "aaaaa"
 urlConsumo : "www.aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
 Consumos
  Tipo      : "abc"
  SubTtipo  : "aaa"
  ...
```

Comment: What have you tried? It this question a programming one, or simply about formatting?

Comment: I suppose that have to use reflection to see each property on listaDatos and make a string of it, but not sure how is the best approach or if there exist something on the net framework 4.0 that allows me to make this in the best way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement a `ToString()` method for the `Consumo` class and then implement a `ToString()` method for the `Datos` class using the `ToString()` method for the `Consumo` class.

Comment: sounds simple and efective, I was sure that if I was used reflection was overkill :) I will wait some other answer but this seems the easiest way for now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must override a "ToString" dafault function like:

```
public class Consumo 
{
    public string Tipo;
    public string Subtipo;
    public string Concepto;
    public string Cantidad;
    public string Importe;
    public string Total;

   public override string ToString()
   {
   return Tipo + " \n " + Subtipo + " \n "... etc;
   }
}
```

refer to the escape sequences section in C# development guide...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx
or
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608

Answer (score 1):

When string representations are used for visualization and similar purposes, the best approach is to override `ToString` method. Start with the most nested type, and go up the hierarchy. Use `ToString` of nested objects to implement `ToString` of outer objects. One very useful method in formatting collections of objects is [`string.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx): it lets you format a collection without an explicit loop.

Comment: thanks for point me on using string.Join for the lists, is easiest to use "string.Join("\r\n", ListaDatos);" than "ListaDatos.Aggregate("", (current, listaDato) => current + (listaDato.ToString() + "\r\n"));"