# Object to string using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there an Razor method that will allow to put "object to string" inside html like:

```
<a href="http://@Model.x.y">Anchor</a>
```

Or do I have to use something like that and change my model?

[c# object to string to display it in text format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693485/c-sharp-object-to-string-to-display-it-in-text-format)

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what your model looks like and what your expected output is.  This can be easy or difficult depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the link you are passing from your model is a string the correct syntax would be

```
 <a href="@Html.Raw(@Model.x.y))">Anchor</a>
```

or

```
<a href=@Html.Raw("http://www." + @Model.x.y))>Anchor</a>
```

This way you are correctly parsing any special characters which might occur in the link like `&` or `=`